# Iphone Draw Line on top of ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have UIViewController and a ScrollView. I add the scrollview as a subview to the UIViewController. The main aim of the scroll view is to add the tiled images. I have basically followed the example provided by developer.apple.com.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

The question is how do I draw line on top of the scrollView. The sample code adds label on top of each tile (i.e. in scroll view class).

Can anyone, explain me on how to draw line on top of the view.

I did try adding lines using

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{

    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 5.0f, 5.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
```

But the problem with this approach is that though the line is being draw its been hidden under the tiled image.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Add the line to a transparent subview that is layered on top of the scrollview?

Comment: Hi, I have tried that option, but by doing that I cant scroll the below subview. Can you pls suggest any other option?

Comment: Ok, so I think the problem is that the layer above which has your line prevents touch events from going to the covered views. A total hack here is to subclass this "line view" from UIView, do your drawing in the drawRect function, and change the hit testing functions so they don't hit on this layer, which will allow them to pass to layers beneath. I've tried this with a layer and a button, but the layer over the button, added my hacked code to the layer, and found that I can click on the button. I havent thought of what issues this could raise, but try it and see where it takes you.

Comment: - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    return nil; //[super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    return nil; //[super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}

Comment: THANKS David. It solves the problem. I was missing these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CAShapeLayer (the code is a lot like what you have now, only building up a path for the CAShapeLayer).  Then you can add the line layer as a sublayer ahead of the other content in the scroll view.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this option and still I am not able to get the lines being drawn.